# Which one is it all-time or all time?

Tags: grammaticality

all time or all-time, not sure which one it is. Are they different in different scenarios?

Comment: This is the best question of all time.  This the the all-time best question.

Answer (score -1):

The rule is: when an adjective modifies another adjective, put in the hyphen.  When both adjectives modify the noun,  no hyphen (and quite possibly put in a comma for clarity).